# compiler can't find vulkan's H264 codec header file

Tags: c++, vulkan, file-not-found

I get `'vulkan/vulkan.h' file not found` due to a different error on `vulkan_core.h`: `vk_video/vulkan_video_codec_h264std.h' file not found`  after running a script using `vulkan.h` header file. The thing is that I have manually checked that the header file exists and that there's no typo

I have downloaded and set up latest vulkan sdk as recommended in the [official documentation](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/latest/linux/getting_started.html), following every step for my system (Fedora Linux). placing `source` of `setup-env.sh` in `.bashrc`, checked that every environment variable needed had a value (except `VK_LAYER_PATH` which i read that its not needed). And runned `vkvia` on the terminal successfully without any errors.

I check that everything works fine by running a test script which includes `vulkan/vulkan.h` header file. But basically, I get an error:
`'vk_video/vulkan_video_codec_h264std.h' file not found`
on `vulkan-core.h` l-8374 (`#include "vk_video/vulkan_video_codec_h264std.h"`)

As I previously said, I manually checked that both `vulkan/vulkan.h` and `vk_video/vulkan_video_codec_h264std.h` exists.

x86_64/include/vk_video directory:

```
vulkan/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.3.268.0/1.3.268.0/x86_64/include/vk_video/
├── vulkan_video_codec_h264std_decode.h
├── vulkan_video_codec_h264std_encode.h
├── vulkan_video_codec_h264std.h
├── vulkan_video_codec_h265std_decode.h
├── vulkan_video_codec_h265std_encode.h
├── vulkan_video_codec_h265std.h
└── vulkan_video_codecs_common.h
```

Well, since it seems like I have to, and even though I dont know how you could reproduce the error on another system, I don't even know if it's vulkan's fault or mine, here's some additional info that you may want to know:
**smallest script where the error happens** <sub>(any with vulkan header file)</sub>

```cpp
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

**every error message I've gotten because of this**

- By the compiler on the script above:

```
fatal error: 'vulkan/vulkan.h' file not found
    2 | #include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

- By the compiler on `vulkan_core.h`

```
clang++: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
/home/owos/vulkan/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.3.268.0/1.3.268.0/x86_64/include/vulkan/vulkan_core.h:8374:10: fatal error: 'vk_video/vulkan_video_codec_h264std.h' file not found
 8374 | #include "vk_video/vulkan_video_codec_h264std.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

**additional information**

- Compiler: Clang

```
$ clang++ -v
clang version 17.0.4 (Fedora 17.0.4-1.fc39)
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

- Compiler Flags: `-Wall -Wextra -g3 -std=c++20` (tried with gcc as well, same c++ version, same error)
- OS: Fedora Linux 39 (GNOME)
- Vulkan version installed: `1.3.268.0`
  If you need `vulkaninfo` content,email me: **p4rtypi5@gmail.com** and I'll give it to you, since its too long to fit in a post

Comment: may I know why I am getting downvoted? It's quite annoying that instead of answers I get a negative number that just seems to get worse with time. If its about me not adding code, I thought it wouldnt be necessary as my code has nothing to do with the error im getting.
If you're going to take the time of your day in reading and downvoting my post you might as well let me know why. I accept criticism as long as the intention is not bad

Comment: I didn't downvote however you probably should edit your question and add the exact text of the error messages + the exact command that was executed by your compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have met the same issue when compiling a project and solved it. Not sure whether we have the same cause of the problem, I will share my solution anyway:

- **Analysis:** Following the error message, the parent folder of `vulkan_core.h` , the `vulkan`, is found to be in `/usr/local/include`, where no folder called `vk_video` can be loaded. This is caused by an incomplete `cp` provided by the official guidance: [screenshot from vulkanSDK installation guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrQXI.png)
- **Solution:** Therefore, you might need to `cp` the `vk_video` folder togerther with the `vulkan` folder under your installation file `1.3.268.0/x86_64/include` by this:

  `cd <your-folder>/1.3.268.0/x86_64/include`

  `sudo cp -r vk_video/ /usr/local/include/`

  Then try to compile it again.

Hope it will help you and good luck with your program!
(This is literally my first answer via this platform, please feel free to correct me if improperly behaved.)

Answer (score 0):

use -I flag to add that directory in includes.
like this:
gcc -I dirctory otherflags source.c
and check man gcc for more info.

Comment: tried what you suggested me to, but that doesnt seem to solve the problem. I tried it with: 

(user dir)/vulkan/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.3.268.0/1.3.268.0/x86_64/include
 and 
(user dir)/vulkan/vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.3.268.0/1.3.268.0/x86_64/include/vulkan/vulkan.hpp (just in case i needed to be more specific)

none of them seem to wrok

Regardless, if i see that i dont get any answers in some time, I'll set vulkan up on a  VM to see if this issue is a thing only from my pc, since i didnt see anyone else complain about this specific thing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).